# Powershell command to confirm SQL Server Smo.Server object is valid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

I had the following code in a PowerShell script:

```
$sql_instance = "SQLEXPRESS"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') 
$server = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $sql_instance
Write-Host $server.InstanceName
```

And nothing was returned. After about 20 minutes of researching I realized I forgot to include the computer name when creating the $server object.

The code should have been:

```
$sql_instance = "MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS"
```

My question is: how can I verify that the server object created is actually representing a valid SQL Server instance?

I imagine something like: `If $server.IsNotValid -eq "True" Then Throw Exception`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$server.ConnectionContext.Connect()
```

will error if you are not able to connect to the server.

Comment: This is great. Interesting coincidence that I spent a good chunk of time yesterday reading your Powershell articles on SQLServerCentral. Thanks!

Comment: Server class is kind of wierd in that it doesn't error out on non-existent servers. BTW you can also read the PowerShell module code at sqlpsx.codeplex.com. The code above comes from the Get-SqlServer function.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot test for a connection to SQL server until you try to retrieve a property (or explicitly make a connection with  server connection) `$conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection`

I can't test it right now but I believe that you will get an error if the connection call fails.  If not you should if you try to retrieve any property.

Comment: FYI it doesn't, and can sometimes return just a blank property.